# Neteller Rest Api

Tags: php, rest, payment-gateway

I have been using Neteller's rest API. I have been struggling to get the correct response for an authentication key, I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.neteller.com/v1/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "clientId:clientSecret");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:application/json", "Cache-Control:no-cache"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query("scope: default"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$serverOutput = curl_exec($curl);

echo $serverOutput;
```

The response I am getting is "invalid_client". I have checked the clientId and secret and they are correct

Thanks
Callum

Comment: Your IP is probably blocked. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28449235/2440

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't send parameters, but string "clientId:clientSecret":

Maybe you mean:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$clientId:$clientSecret");
```

Also you may be calling the wrong url, for example for test environments you must call:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://test.api.neteller.com/v1/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials");
```

Answer (score 1):

I just take your example and it's working for me:

```
$username = 'MerchantXYZ';
$password = 'B81dff9bb4020a89e8ac44cdfdcecd702151182fdc952272661d290ab2e5849e31bb03deede';
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.neteller.com/v1/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:application/json", "Cache-Control:no-cache"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("scope"=>"default"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$serverOutput = curl_exec($curl);

echo $serverOutput;
```

The response:

> { "accessToken": "B.AQBBBAAAUnzfOwkAAAAAAAEk-BRM0QBTOoehaumwlvdwjqX.EAAQ0NOOTDeY2aMHUCwH4YCugGUX4ro", "tokenType": "Bearer", "expiresIn": 300 }

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is invalid as `http_build_query()` expects an array as input but you are providing a string.

Try changing that line to:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("scope"=>"default"));
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your help! I have changed the line accordingly and still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

When using the client_credentials flow, scope is not relevant.  It only applies to the authorization_grant flow, anything tagged 'default' scope doesn't require member authorization.  Resource fiels with 'default' would be returned using basic client_credentials, with no need to ask the member for permission.